# Отображение русских букв шрифта Myriad Pro в Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, шрифты

Странный баг обнаружил — заюзал шрифт `Myriad Pro`, `14px` и увидел вот такие чудеса:

[image]

Как побороть? Доктайп `<!DOCTYPE html>`, Google Chrome — последняя версия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для уверенности, что шрифт будет работать правильно, пользуетесь `@font-face` ?
если нет, его очень удобно генерировать сервисом [@font-face kit generator](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/).
И открою Вам секрет, G-Chrome любит некорректно отображать кириллические шрифты.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Про сервис конечно знаю, но Myriad Pro по идее идет в комплекте с ОС. Да и тем более она платная.